# Select largest date from column based on another column in table

Tags: sql, microsoft-query

I'm new to SQL. Trying to get a certain date for jobs from a table. The only way to get these dates is to look to a massive table where every item for each job is stored with a last transaction date. The date I want is the largest date in the lst_trx_date column for each job.

The data in the table looks something like this:
[image: Datatable Image]

Where each job has a varying amount of items. My biggest hurdle and my main question: How can I instead of selecting the entire job table only select the largest lst_trx_date for each job? I initially brought in the data using microsoft query, but I realize my request will probably require modifying the SQL command text directly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. First, figure out which RDBMS you're using. Then see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it would be along these lines:

```
SELECT job, MAX(lst_trx_date) as job, last_transaction_date
FROM table
GROUP BY job
ORDER BY lst_trx_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. this will give you the max date

```
SELECT MAX (lst_trx_date) AS "Max Date" 
FROM table where job = 1234;
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest date for each job, you can use windowing functions. As an example try:

```
    select job, item, lst_trx_date from (select job, item, lst_trx_date, row_number() 
                                         over(partition by stat,job,item order by 
                                         lst_trx_date desc) rn
                                        from <table>)t
    where rn = 1
```